# Show the number of open sessions on a spanner database

Tags: session, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Is there a way to display the number of currently open sessions on a database in google spanner?

The limit is mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/quotas):

> Sessions per database per node - 10,000

I have looked through the documentation on SQL functions and `gcloud spanner` command line tool, but neither mentioned a way to show how many were open.

Comment: For context I think my application may not be closing sessions properly and it hit the limit.  I want to be able to monitor the number of open sessions so I can figure out if I have fixed the problem before I hit the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a command to list active sessions:

`gcloud spanner databases sessions list --instance <your-spanner-instance> --database <your-database>`

You can then parse this file or count the lines and figure out how many open sessions there are.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this isn't something exposed at this time. You can see a list of metrics available for [Stackdriver in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics#gcp-spanner):

[image: List of Cloud Spanner metrics available in Stackdriver]

Comment: This is really causing pain for us.  We have twice used up the 30k sessions in our spanner database with no recourse but to wait until sessions expire.  There is no way for us to monitor this value and alert before we hit the limit.

Comment: If there was a way to list active sessions we could count them and possibly even force close all of them to at least get our production service back online when this happens.